# css not loading in ipad

Tags: css, ipad

Recently someone pointed out that my personal site was not working on ipad, because of the fact that the css did not load. How is this possible? On iphone the system works ok and also on any other platform. Could it be because I load all my stylesheets through one master.css for faster download times.
My personal website is: 
webofdreams.ro

Did anyone encountered the same problem ever?

Comment: I just tested it in the iOS SDK and it loads the same as the desktop version of Chrome. Have you see this issue in person?

Comment: I have only seen it on iphone and it was rendered perfectly. This was pointed out to my be a client from US so I can't say that the problem is not with his browser or system.

Comment: I tried iOS 5 & 5.1 in the SDK, can't repro.

Comment: I got to talk more with the client and it turned out that the css on homepage was not loading due to a loop on the browser, I guess it was local problem with the client browser, it happens from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think thats actually "faster". its best to put all your css into one sheet for minimal http requests.

As a sidenote, it loads on my ipad but you have a semi-transparent div blocking everything.

Comment: What do you mean exactly that a div blocks everything??
On another sidenote it seemed to have been a problem. I have tested it in IBBDemo2 and the CSS were not loading. This happened due to the fact that I loaded all the CSS through one stylesheet. For some reason some of those devices don't seem to recognize the @import url command. So for people who want to be compatible with this market this is a no no.
Thx for taking the time to answer and for your help.